# R ggplot2 geom_text legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

is there anyway to get a legend from geom_text?

I am having a map. I want to print abbreviations from the districts onto the map and in the legend I want to have the abbreviations and their full names. The Data comes from a csv file.

With this code i am currently printing the abbreviations on the map:

`geom_text( data=testdata,aes(x=long, y=lat, label=abbreviation), colour="black", size=4 )`

Reproducible example from my data. shape_f is the data for the map, testdata is having the abbrevations and the full names.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0G5fic4Fxh8fnhnWnJRU3NSQ1pQeXNVRElFWVZKdERxT2F6ek9PQW95TFVOWHZvcDAtOXM&usp=sharing

i am trying it with

`mytable <- cbind(sites= testdata["abbreviation"], testdata["full_name"])
annotation_custom(tableGrob(mytable), xmin = 16, xmax = 17, ymin = 47.5, ymax = 49)`

but the output is way to big(28 rows).
is there anyway to change the font size?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example of `testdata` using (for example) `dput(head(testdata, 20))`? That would let someone test their solution before providing it.

Comment: You might consider adding a table to the graphic, such as below it.  The table would show the abbreviations and full names.

Comment: @DavidRobinson added example